# EntityFramework's AddOrUpdate leads to incorrect foreign key update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have a number of countries, each of which has a number of cities.  I can represent this using the following models:

```
public class Country
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual int CountryId { get; set; }
}

class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework correctly identifies the foreign keys and generates the tables.

However, if I now try to seed some test data:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestContext>());
        using (var db = new TestContext())
        {
            db.Database.Initialize(true);
            db.Database.Log = Console.Write;

            var country = db.Countries.Create();
            country.Name = "France";
            db.Countries.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Name, country);

            var city = db.Cities.Create();
            city.Name = "Paris";
            city.Country = country;
            db.Cities.AddOrUpdate(q => q.Name, city);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The first time this is run, all is fine, and the CountryId field in the database is set properly.  However, when I run it a second time, `db.SaveChanges()` attemps to set the CountryId of Paris to 0, which violates the non-nullable foreign key constraint.

The problem seems to be that despite `city` and `country` being change-tracking proxies, the `CountryId` property is never updating.  Updating it manually doesn't help this, though.

Is this the intended behaviour, and if so, how can I use `AddOrUpdate` without changing like this?  Doing everything by setting foreign keys doesn't seem to be an option, as those aren't available the first time the code runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `AddOrUpdate` doesn't support navigation properties. Also when `AddOrUpdate` doesn't get any property by input it will save it with default value of property.

In your stiuation you use navigation property.

```
 city.Name = "Paris";
 city.Country = country;
```

But `AddOrUpdate` doesn't assign `city.CountryId=country.Id` by internally because of lack of support navigation property. So your `city.CountryId` value becomes 0 which is default value for int.

You should assign foreign key by yourself.

```
 var city = db.Cities.Create();
 city.Name = "Paris";
 city.Country = country;
 db.Cities.AddOrUpdate(q => q.Name, city);
```

should be like this

```
 var city = db.Cities.Create();
 city.Name = "Paris";
 city.Country = country;
 //Assign foreign key by manually.
 city.CountryId = country.Id;
 db.Cities.AddOrUpdate(q => q.Name, city);
```

I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this...

```
[Key]
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```